# Swift - Core graphics and setting background color?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I created this method that generates and image out of an original one but adds padding to the new image according to a given size. Everything works fine except the background color of the image is always black although I set white as fill color. Any idea how to fix this?

```
public extension UIImage {

    public func imageCenteredInParentWithSize(size: CGSize, backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), true, 0.0)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context);

        let origin = CGPointMake(
            (size.width - self.size.width) / 2.0,
            (size.height - self.size.height) / 2.0
        )

        backgroundColor.setFill()
        drawAtPoint(origin)

        UIGraphicsPopContext()
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the working version

```
public func imageCenteredInParentWithSize(size: CGSize, backgroundColor: UIColor = UIColor.clearColor()) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(size.width, size.height), true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    let origin = CGPointMake(
        (size.width - self.size.width) / 2.0,
        (size.height - self.size.height) / 2.0
    )

    backgroundColor.setFill()
    CGContextFillRect(context,  CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
    drawAtPoint(origin)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line `backgroundColor.setFill()` just sets the fill color of the current context, it doesn't actually do the filling. One way of performing the fill is to call `CGContextFillRect(context, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))` after setting the fill color.

Additionally, you should probably pass the `scale` of the `UIImage` as the `scale` parameter in `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` rather than `0.0`. Also, you don't need the push- and pop-context lines at all - you're already working the in current context.

Comment: Awesome, this fixed the issue, will update my question with the correction

Comment: It is fine to use `0.0` as a scale, as this is the same as `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale` according to the documentation: "If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen."

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you're setting your background color to "Clear" (as in no color) which means it will show whatever color is set on the background view... which is almost certainly black.

You need to set the default to "UIColor.whiteColor()".

Comment: The background view is not black, it's white. UIColor.whiteColor().setFill() doesn't fix it either so issue seems to be somewhere else